# Enabling a button only if two fields are filled

Tags: c++, qt

How to implement such functionality that a button is enabled only if two lineEdit's are filled with text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to monitor both line edits for changes:

```
connect(lineEdit1, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), SLOT(checkShouldEnableButton()));
connect(lineEdit2, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), SLOT(checkShouldEnableButton()));
```

And then you need to enable/disable the button when text is present in both:

```
void YourWidget::checkShouldEnableButton() {
    button->setEnabled(
        !lineEdit1->text().isEmpty() && !lineEdit2->text().isEmpty()
        );
}
```

If you only care about user edits, you can use the [textEdited(const QString&)](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlineedit.html#textEdited) signal instead of the [textChanged](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlineedit.html#textChanged) signal.

Comment: Can you connect mismatched signals/slots like that? Not to disparage a competing answer but what happens to the truncated parameter?

Comment: @spraff being a function call without arguments it just calls the method... The other way around is not possible.

Comment: As @RedX pointed out, Qt has no problem discarding unnecessary arguments. The arguments that are present, however, must be of the same type in order for the `connect` call to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Connect both widgets' `textChanged` signal to the same slot, which calls

```
button -> setEnabled (edit1 -> text .size () && edit2 -> text .size ())
```